# System.out.println with java volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have an example like that:

```
public class MainApp {

    private volatile static int MY_INT = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread1().start();
        new Thread2().start();
    }

    static class Thread1 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                MY_INT++;
                System.out.println("1 : " + MY_INT);
            }
        }
    }

    static class Thread2 extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                MY_INT++;
                System.out.println("2 : " + MY_INT);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
1 : 1
2 : 2
1 : 3
2 : 4
1 : 5
1 : 7
1 : 8
1 : 9
1 : 10
2 : 6
1 : 11
1 : 13
```

I don't understand why after printing 1:10 and the next line is 2:6. Can anyone explain the result? Thanks in advance

Comment: `MY_INT++` is not atomic, and making a variable volatile doesn't make it threadsafe. Consider using [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Comment: Also it goes from `1 : 5` to `1 : 7` skipping the 6

Comment: Can you explain more detail? @khelwood

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: the 6 is on line 2 (`2:6`)

Comment: I think that code work like that: After thread 1 print '1 : 5'. Thread 2 run the command MY_INT++. Then Thread 1 run, so it print '1 : 7', and continue until printing '1 : 10'.Then, Thread 2 run, so i think the result should be '2 : 10'. Can anyone explain what i am wrong?

Comment: Value 6 was passed to println method. Now thread 2 was waiting to access IO to print, by the time thread2 got access to IO then 6 is printed. You can add two print statements to see the next would have print the updated value

Comment: `MY_INT++` involves reading a variable, changing the value, and writing it back. If another thread can update the variable at the same time, then the wrong value can end up being written.

Comment: But method println is synchronized, so why value 6 passed in thread 2, the thread 1 still avaiable to print? I think thread 1 must wait thread 2 print value 6 and then thread 2 is able to print value 7 @nits.kk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PrintStream in `System.out` and the volatile field `MY_INT` are independently synchronized, so the following can happen:

```
Thread 1               Thread 2
read MY_INT = 4
write MY_INT = 5
read MY_INT = 5
                       read MY_INT = 5
                       write MY_INT = 6
                       read MY_INT = 6
println 5
read MY_INT = 6
write MY_INT = 7
read MY_INT = 7
println 7

...
                       println 6
```

That is, because the volatile field and the PrintStream returned by System.out are independently synchronized, printing may occur in non-ascending order.

The following could also happen:

```
Thread 1            Thread 2
read MY_INT = 1
                    read MY_INT = 1
write MY_INT = 2
                    write MY_INT = 2
read MY_INT = 2
println 2
                    read MY_INT = 2
                    println 2
```

because ++MY_INT is actually compiled into a read, a computation, and a write. Since volatile reads and writes are separate synchronization actions, other threads may act in between, and mess the counter up.

If you want ascending numbers being printed by separate threads, the easiest way is:

```
void run() {
   while (true) {
       synchronized (lock) {
           MY_INT++;
           System.out.println("1 : " + MY_INT);
       }
   }
}
```

where `lock` is an object shared by all threads accessing MY_INT.

Comment: I want to askt your first code. After Thread 2 write MY_INT = 6, and thread 1 println 5. So It println 5 or println value of MY_INT. If it println 5, can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Edited the example log to show when MY_INT is being read for printing. In short, both 5 and 6 are possible, it depends whether MY_INT is being read for printing before or after the other thread has incremented MY_INT. In your case, it was read before the other thread updated.

Comment: Your example has the line: println 5. So it actually println 5 or println MY_INT (value = 5)?

Comment: The statement `System.out.println("1 : " + MY_INT)` is executed by fetching the string, reading MY_INT, concatentating the two, and passing this to the println method. When I write println 5, I mean that 5 is passed to the println method. The key observation is that reading MY_INT, and passing the string to println are seperate actions, and it is possible for other threads to run in the meantime.

Comment: Oh, i got it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues here:

- threads may not run in parallel. They run in time slices (default: 15.6 ms on a PC; 64 ticks per second, see [timer resolution (Microsoft)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx)). This is why you don't see `1:x` and `2:x` one after another, but several `1:x` after each other.
- using `volatile` does not help with synchronization. You need real synchronization objects such as `AtomicInteger` or the `synchronized` keyword. Therefore you may see skipped numbers (not the case in your output, but it may occur). You need the synchronization around both, the `++` and the `println()` if you want to see unique numbers
- Console output is buffered and synchronized, because you don't want 2 `println` statements to mix the output on one line

Comment: The last point is the key to the OP's question: through some accident of the scheduling, although the second thread incremented the value to `6` somewhere between the first thread incrementing it  `5` and `7`, the output from that time didn't make it to the screen until after several of the outputs from the first thread.

Comment: Can you link to a reference to the 17ms?   That seems like an arbitrary number that, given modern multi-processor boxes, running at Ghz speeds, seems like a huge amount of time.

Comment: @Gray: the default Windows timer ticks 64 times per second. That's 15.6 ms. http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx

Comment: @Gray And yes, I think the modern CPU speed is why there can be a huge performance increase using tasks/promises/futures over "normal" multithreading. In a single time slot, today, a thread can process dozens if not hundreds of those new lightweight items.